# removing previous value and adding new in firestore list flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Here in firestore I want to update list with new values entered by the user and to remove all previous values. Suppose user add 2 new values [American English, French]. What I want is to remove all the values in the list and update the list with these values. I have used set and update method and it is just adding new values in newer index but not removing previous.

[image]

here is my code.

```
     addCategoriesAndSkillsInDB({List categories, List skills}) async {
    print('$skills');
    categories == null
        ? _firestore
            .collection('users')
            .doc(getCurrentUser().uid)
            .set({'skills': skills})
        : _firestore
            .collection('users')
            .doc(getCurrentUser().uid)
            .update({'categories': FieldValue.arrayUnion(categories)});
  }
```

and that is how I am retaining new values in the list

```
import 'file:///E:/flutterProject/filmmaker/lib/auth_screens/signUp_screens/worker/signUp_screen5.dart';
import 'package:filmmaker/auth_screens/signUp_screens/worker/signUp_screen14.dart';
import 'package:filmmaker/logic/bloc/fields/fields_bloc.dart';
import 'package:filmmaker/resources/repo/firebase_repo.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class SignUpScreen4 extends StatefulWidget {
  bool edit = false;

  SignUpScreen4([this.edit]);

  @override
  _SignUpScreen4State createState() => _SignUpScreen4State();
}

class _SignUpScreen4State extends State<SignUpScreen4> {
  List<String> _dynamicChips = [];
  String _value;
  final key = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('Sign Up Screen 4'),
            Form(
              key: key,
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: controller,
                validator: (value) =>
                    value.trim().isEmpty || value == null ? 'Empty Text' : null,
                autofocus: true,
                autocorrect: true,
                enableSuggestions: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText:
                      'Type things like: Final Cut Pro, or Documentary making',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                  labelText: 'Tell us about some of your skills',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (key.currentState.validate()) {
                  if (!_dynamicChips.contains(controller?.text)) {
                    setState(() {
                      _value = controller?.text;
                    });
                    _dynamicChips.add(_value);
                    controller.text = '';
                  }
                }
              },
              child: Text("Add"),
            ),
            dynamicChips(),
            BlocConsumer<FieldsBloc, FieldsState>(builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is FieldsInitial) {
                return Container();
              } else if (state is FieldSuccessfulState) {
                return Container();
              } else if (state is FieldUnsuccessfulState) {
                return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.error,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          state.message,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ));
              }
              return Container();
            }, listener: (context, state) {
              if (state is FieldSuccessfulState)
                widget.edit
                    ? Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignUpScreen14()))
                    : Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignUpScreen5()));
            }),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  BlocProvider.of<FieldsBloc>(context)
                      .add(NextButtonEventScreen4(_dynamicChips));
                },
                child: Text('Next'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  dynamicChips() {
    return Wrap(
      spacing: 6.0,
      runSpacing: 6.0,
      children: List<Widget>.generate(
          _dynamicChips?.length,
          (int index) => Chip(
                label: Text(_dynamicChips[index]),
                onDeleted: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _dynamicChips.removeAt(index);
                  });
                },
              )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `print(otherLanguage)` before updating to firestore... And confirm if whether its a list of just the added new values ... or if its a list of the added values and the previous values

Comment: "it is just adding new values in newer index but not removing previous" Nothing in the code you shared explains that behavior. Then again, we have no way to know how you initialize `otherLanguage`, so it could be the problem is in there. Please edit your question to include the [minimum, complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i have checked that and the otherLanguage is containing the newer values in list not the previous. But the newer values are getting merged with older values in firestore I just want to remove old values and and maintain new values in list

Comment: I have figured out the solution. The update methode is working fine all i need to to is to reinstall the application and everything is perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `List` instead of `String`. For example

```
List<String> languages = ['English', 'Nepali', 'hindi'];
```

and then,

```
_firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(getCurrentUser().uid)
        .update({'other languages': languages});
```